# Simplest way to save array variables as images C++

Tags: c++, arrays, image, vector, save

```
#include "Readvid.h"
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <atlstr.h>


//skeleton data
SLR_ST_Sn sn = myReadVideo.vSknData[i];
        //RGB image
IplImage* color = myReadVideo.vColorData[i];
```

I'm a beginner in C++ and I need to save values of sn and color array variables as images. Is there an easy way to do it like in python where we only need to import cv2 and write cv2.imwrite?

Comment: A Google search for "opencv imwrite" returns a helpful pointer to documentation for using this function in C or C++, as the very first link, for me. Did you try using Google to find the information you're looking for? Having said that, the rule of thumb is that answer to every "is there an easy way to do <X> in C++" is always the same: no. C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. That documentation is just the starting point. Then you need to read further documentation that explains further what all the parameters are, and how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

The code you are using is OpenCV in C. In OpenCV C++, you can use function cv::imwrite() to write your images to files

Comment: Thank you. How do we specify the file path. As in like (in python):

cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path , 'waka.jpg'), img)

i'd also need the filename to correspond to the current [i] in vSknData[i]

Comment: you can use the absolute path or relative path. you can see [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite) There are a bunch of documentations of opencv. Please google first.